# Calculate future price with continuous compounding

Tags: derivatives, economics

A forward contract for 4 months is entered into when a stock index is at 1000.  If the risk free interest rate is 3% per year (with continuous compounding) and the dividend yield on the index is 2% per year, what is the futures price?  After 1 month the index price is 980, what is the value of the futures agreement assuming the risk free rate with continuous compounding is now 5% (but the original dividend rate remains 2%) and the contract price is equal to $50 times the index value?

For the first part of the question I used the following equation to find the futures price F<sub>0</sub> = 1,000*e<sup>(0.03-0.02)*(4/12)</sup> = $1,003.3389. However, I'm not sure what to do with the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $V_{t,T}$ of a long forward contract at time $t$ with expiry $T$ is given by the discounted change in the forward index times the contract price per index point, $P$.  We can express the value as

$$\begin{align}
V_{t,T}&=P\left(F_{t,T}-F_{0,T}\right)e^{-r_{t}(T-t)}\\\\
&=P(S_te^{(r_t-\delta_{t})(T-t)}-S_0e^{(r_{0}-\delta_{0})T})e^{-r_{t}(T-t)}
\end{align}$$

where $S_0$ and $S_t$ are the spot indices on the purchase date and valuation date, respectively, $r_{0}$ and $r_t$ are the interest rates on the purchase date and valuation date, respectively, $\delta_0$ and $\delta_t$ are the dividend yield of the underlying stock on the purchase date and valuation date, respectively, $t$ is the number of years between the purchase and valuation dates, and $T$ is the number of years between the purchase and expiry dates.

We are given $P=\$50.00$, $S_0=1000$, $S_t=980$, $r_{0}=3%$, $r_{t}=5%$, $\delta_{0}=\delta_{t}=2%$, $T=1/3$, and $t=1/12$.

The numerical evaluation is left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: Thanks. In your equation what is $-r_t,_t$ I plugged the numbers into your equation, using .05 as $-r_t,_t$, and got $$50(980e^{(.05-.02)(1/3 - 1/12)}-1000e^{(.03-.02)1/3})e^{-.05(1/3-1/12)}$$ which equals -788.149. This is definitely not correct, though.

Comment: Mark, you're welcome.  My pleasure.  Mark, why do you believe that your  answer is incorrect?  Neglect the interest rates and dividend yield.  The index decreased $20$ points, which after multiplying by $50$ per point, the value would have decreased by $1000$.  Now, the term "$r_{t,t}$" is a typographical error.  It should have read "r_t$.  I've edited.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. The equation tells me the gain/loss (in this case loss) from the change in the futures contract.

Comment: Yes.  On Day $0$, the value is $0$ since the forward price is "fair."  On future days, the new value is, therefore, the change in MTM value and hence the P&L.